# Create a new decorator from an existing one

Tags: python, python-decorators, dramatiq

I'm using [dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/) for my task queue which offers the decorator [`@dramatiq.actor`](https://github.com/Bogdanp/dramatiq/blob/master/dramatiq/actor.py#L157) to decorate a function as a task. I've tried to write my own decorator that wraps the `@dramatiq.actor` decorator so I can add a default argument to the `@dramatiq.actor` decorator that applies to all tasks (The argument I'm talking about is `priority=100`).

For some reason I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: foobar() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

If I switch my custom `@task` decorator with the `@dramatiq.actor` it works so I guess my custom decorator isn't correct but I can't spot my mistake.

*decorators.py*

```
def task(func=None, **kwargs):    
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        @dramatiq.actor(priority=100, **kwargs)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    if func is None:
        return decorator

    return decorator(func)
```

*tasks.py*

```
@task
def foobar(entry_pk):
    ...
```

*views.py*

```
foobar.send_with_options(args=(entry.pk,))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be much easier to use [**`functools.partial`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

task = partial(dramatiq.actor, priority=100)

@task
def foobar(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

This allows you to preemptively add an argument to a function without actually calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to subclass the `Dramatiq` class and override the `actor` method.  That approach plus some other tips described here - https://blog.narrativ.com/converting-celery-to-dramatiq-a-py3-war-story-23df217b426